# In python, what's the most efficient way to combine 3 dicts and to sort by one of the dict's keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

Example:

```
list1 = {'52': {'timestamp':'1234567890', 'name':'Jason Bourne'},
         '42': {'timestamp':'2345678891', 'name':'Sarah Parker'}
         }

list2 = {'61': {'timestamp':'3456789012', 'name':'Mike Williams'},
         '12': {'timestamp':'4567889123', 'name':'Robert Tissone'}
         }

list3 = {'56': {'timestamp':'4567890123', 'name':'Peter Blake'},
         '71': {'timestamp':'5678891234', 'name':'Alex Cheng'}
         }

//Best way to combine list1, list2, and list3 and sort by timestamp

result = [ {'timestamp':'1234567890', 'name':'Jason Bourne'},
           {'timestamp':'2345678891', 'name':'Sarah Parker'},
           {'timestamp':'3456789012', 'name':'Mike Williams'},
           {'timestamp':'4567889123', 'name':'Robert Tissone'},
           {'timestamp':'4567890123', 'name':'Peter Blake'},
           {'timestamp':'5678891234', 'name':'Alex Cheng'}
         ]
```

Comment: OP - are you sure you don't mind losing the keys?  If so Ignacio's response is spot on

Comment: Yeah, I can lose the keys.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sorted(itertools.chain(list1.itervalues(), list2.itervalues(),
    list3.itervalues()), key=operator.itemgetter('timestamp'))
```

Comment: Remember that you need to import itertools before this will work.

Comment: Finally, remember that since your timestamp is a string, string-style sorting is what you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter

def sortedchain(dicos, key):
    return sorted(chain(v for d in dicos for v in d.values()), key=itemgetter(key))

dicos=[list1, list2, list3]
sortedvalues = sortedchain(dicos, 'timestamp')
```

So that **dicos** may have any lenght